# onReceive of BroadcastReceiver not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

onReceive of BroadcastReceiver not working.

I am trying different ways.

Here is my current code.

Activity code

```
BroadcastReceiver _receiver;
public static final String SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION =
        "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    IntentFilter _intentFilter = new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION);
    _intentFilter.setPriority(1234567);

    registerReceiver(_receiver,_intentFilter);

    _receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };


}
```

manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: You should initialize a variable before using it.

Comment: have you right _receiver in manifest

Comment: No. i think no need of it.  @NaveenTamrakar

Comment: Have you added your uses-permission outside Application tag or inside in your manifest?

Comment: please give runtime permission in your app

Answer (score 1):

Create your _receiver before registering it

```
_intentFilter.setPriority(999);

_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

registerReceiver(_receiver,_intentFilter);
```

The `priority` should be bigger than -1000 and smaller than 1000

*Documentation*

> android:priority
>   The priority that should be given to the parent component with regard to handling intents of the type described by the filter. This attribute has meaning for both activities and broadcast receivers:
>
> It provides information about how able an activity is to respond to an intent that matches the filter, relative to other activities that could also respond to the intent. When an intent could be handled by multiple activities with different priorities, Android will consider only those with higher priority values as potential targets for the intent.
>
> It controls the order in which broadcast receivers are executed to receive broadcast messages. Those with higher priority values are called before those with lower values. (The order applies only to synchronous messages; it's ignored for asynchronous messages.)
>   Use this attribute only if you really need to impose a specific order in which the broadcasts are received, or want to force Android to prefer one activity over others.
>
> The value must be an integer, such as "100". Higher numbers have a higher priority. The default value is 0. The value must be greater than -1000 and less than 1000.

Comment: i made this changes. but, onReceive not fired when message received.  is there any API level or device level dependency

Comment: Try again. I just update the answer @Maheshshankhpal

Comment: It's working.. Now Problem is on marshmello device.  priority smaller than 1000 is not valid. Now i am set it to 465421312.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html @Maheshshankhpal

Comment: If this is the answer for you. Please accept and upvote it :P